# Laravel5 display table counts

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have an admin site and on each page I want to display the counts for each of 5 tables.

I understand how to get the count out of the tables, but I am looking for help as to where to perform the "count" action and a best practice for storing or caching those values to be used in the blade.  There are only 5 so it's not a huge load on the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform the `count` in controller. But if your db tables update frequently, I think is not so right to use cache, because if you display the cached result may not be accurate.

[Laravel cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache)

Comment: I’d go for this advice. Best practice is not to cache. Also, you could use count in blade with a variable from from controller or do it directly in controller as suggested above